# VBA cells.find return values instead of address

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets in same workbook, sheets("送達地址") store raw data, sheets("送達證書") for user type the string which they want to find, as code below.

```
Private Sub OpenAddress()

Dim addressNum As Integer
Dim addressString As String
Dim name As String
Dim findCell As Range

Count = TB1.Value
'TB1.Value is the string which type by user

Set findCell = Worksheets("送達地址").Columns("A").Cells.Find(what:=Count, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

If findCell Is Nothing Then

MsgBox "not found"
isPass = False

Exit Sub

End If

For i = 1 To People

S = 2

With Worksheets("送達地址")
    .findCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = name
    .findCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = addressNum
    .findCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = addressString

End With

With Worksheets("送達證書")

.Cells(S, 1).Value = name
.Cells(S, 3).Value = addressNum & "  " & addressString

S = S + 1
i = i + 1

End With

Next i

S = 2

End Sub
```

The problem is, variable findCell result in return the string you type instead of the address of it.

Ex: You want find where the string "1" is, but findCell return "1" 
instead of return the address "1" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually returning a range object (one cell), with the value of the cell being displayed when you hover over it. You don’t need the first With statement, the findcell.offset will work without the “.” In front of it.